# Dojotoolkit uncaught exception : could not load cross domain resources

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am able to get the dojo working on my site and AccordionContainer dijit that I am using is working fine. except that I get the error below continously.
"Dojotoolkit uncaught exception : could not load cross domain resources"

I tried to locate and fix the issue from the discussions on the same topic here at SO and else where without any succcess.

[http://www.campaniola.ibr.co.il/][1] is the URL in case any of you want to check.

It helps me great deal, If I can be pointed to the right discussion forum/fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your site but it seems you switched to JQuery. But to answer your question, if you were using a CDN version of dojo you can get crossdomain errors when dojo tries to access an iframe from another domain. Including the domain of the page.

Comment: Dre, Thankyou very much for your response, I switched my site to jQuery after waiting couple days for an answer here. I'll check based on your response and post the results here when I get a chance. Again, Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your referencing cross domain resources, please check if all the resource urls are loaded properly, by checking the "net" section of the firebug. In my case i was able to see the dojo.xd.js cdn resource was not loading due to firwall/security settings. Hope this helps. Thanks.